# What is a good approximation for a page's (Google) search rank to come back to it's original rank, after it has fallen due to technical errors?

Tags: seo, google, web-crawlers, pagerank

Say we had a web page, which initially had a google rank on the first page.

Say these errors occurred after some time:

- load time
- Meta title changes
- Some data not being visible to the crawler
- etc.

Due to these errors say that we lost our first page rank.

After fixing the above errors, what is a good estimate of time to wait for the rankings to come back?

Or is there a strong possibility, that once the rank is lost, it won't rank again?

Answer (score 1):

It should come back okay.

But don't think search engines remember anything - they don't. Once the page is fetched, it will have to go through the usual processes. Generally, 1-2 months is fair. Sometimes sooner depending upon competition and how fast the search engine discovers the page.

JIC, you can always use the Fetch as Google and Submit to Index options in Search Console. It is not immediate. The regular googlebot will come by in a day or two and then the process will begin. It is a good option for the occasional Ooopppsss!! Nertz!!